# How to test use of DI (NInject)

Tags: .net, testing, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that has a NInject container for dependency injection.  As advertised, IoC makes it pretty easy for me to test components in isolation, and then easy to compose components in the application.

I want to test my use of the DI.  I don't want to test that the DI component operates correctly.  I trust that the NInject folks do that pretty well.  I want to test that I have used the DI to compose components correctly with respect to my application's intentions.  I don't want to test NInject, I want to test my use of NInject.  (I also don't want to try to categorize this as a unit test or an integration test.  I only want to be able to, sometime before I get to production, demonstrate why I have confidence that my particular use of NInject works.)

Suppose I have something like:

```
    private static void RegisterDatabaseConnections(IBindingRoot kernel)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        kernel.Bind<IProvideDbConnections>()
            .To<Connector>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<ActivityStore>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
        kernel.Bind<IProvideDbConnections>()
            .To<Connector>()
            .WhenInjectedInto<CrConnector>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);
        kernel.Bind<IProvideDbConnections>()
            .To<CrConnector>()
        ...
    }
```

Somewhere I have:

```
    public class Writer
    {
        public Writer(IProvideDBConnections connector)
        {
            Connector = connector;
        }
        private IProvideDBConnections Connector { get; set; }
        ....
    }
```

I would like to write an MSTest like

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestThatWriterCrConnectorContainsConnector()
    {
        ...
    }
```

so that I can verify that I wrote `RegisterDatabaseConnections` to give me what I expect.  I am having trouble getting started down that path, because I don't know to access a kernel to set up any tests.  The code that starts the kernel in the application is a collection of static private methods, and is a little mysterious to me, and I don't see how I would do this in the context of a test.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create my own kernel and `Load()` the module(s) you are wanting to test.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestThatWriterCrConnectorContainsConnector()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Load(new ModuleA(), new ModuleB());

    var obj = kernel.Get<Writer>();
    // ... assert
}
```

this is assuming you have defined all your bindings that you want to test in a `NinjectModule`